# Electron - Change Menu Bar in Different Windows

Tags: menu, electron

In my electron app, a user can open different windows.

I have the menu initialized when the main window is created like so:

```
const menuContents = Menu.buildFromTemplate(menuTemplate(mainWindow))
Menu.setApplicationMenu(menuContents)
```

However, when a user clicks a link and opens a new window, this same menu bar still appears in that window. I would like to change it and/or completely remove it.

How would I do that?

Comment: Do the new opened windows use the same code as the main window (which apparently creates the menu bar)?

Comment: No. The format of the menus are different. The solution that I did was every time a window (that doesn't use the same menu as main) was opened, I recreate the menu bar.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible:

[Example for Menus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLl9a.gif)

In Renderer or Main Proccess make two functions with menu templates like this:

### main menu

```
function createMenu(){
    var menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
    {
        //your menu items
    }
    ])
    Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
}
```

### second menu

```
function createMenuwin(){
    var menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
    {
        //your other window menu items
    }
    ])
    Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
}
```

### when you call the second window : Example open an image

```
function openIMG(path){
    win = new BrowserWindow({  
        width: 800, 
        height: 550,
       frame: true, 
        vibrancy: 'medium-light',
    });
    win.loadFile(path);
    createMenuwin();
    win.on('close', () =>{
        createMenu();
    })
}
```

### when the second window is open create an app menu with

```
createmenuwin()
```

### when the second window is closed call the event:

```
win.on('close', () =>{})
```

### inside the close event of the second window, call:

```
 createMenu();
```